# How do you simulate a useEffect to update state while testing React with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I'm diving into testing React for the first time. I have an app completely built out, and I'm adding tests now. I'm using React-Testing-Library with Jest.

In order to test that the component is rendering as I expect, I need to update a few pieces of state, which happens through an axios call in a useEffect hook. Once 3 sets of data are fetched, another useEffect runs and sets a piece of state called loaded to true, and I want to test what happens after that.

Using React-Testing-Library and Jest, how would I mock / simulate these state updates. Example of the component is below.
Help much appreciated!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Spinner from 'path-to-spinner';

const Example = () => {
  const [data1, setData1] = useState(null);
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(null);
  const [data3, setData3] = useState(null);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data1 && !data2 && !data3) {
      axios.get('apiResource1').then((res) => setData1(res.data));
      axios.get('apiResource2').then((res) => setData2(res.data));
      axios.get('apiResource3').then((res) => setData3(res.data));
    }
  }, [data1, data2, data3]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data1 && data2 && data3 && !loaded) {
      setLoaded(true);
    }
  }, [loaded, data1, data2, data3]);

  return !loaded ? <Spinner /> : <HTML I want rendered />
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't really need to simulate the `useEffect`. What you really are wanting to simulate are the API calls made by axios.

I would recommend mocking the entire axios module *OR* making helper functions for each of those api calls, and then mocking those functions.

For example, create helper function:

```
async function apiCall1() {
     const res = await axios.get('apiResource1');
     return res.data;
}
```

then use those helper functions in the `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!data1 && !data2 && !data3) {
      apiCall1().then(data => setData1(data));
      // etc.
    }
}, [data1, data2, data3]);
```

Now in your tests you can mock the helper functions or SpyOn them and mock their implementation.

```
import helperFunctions from './helperFunctions';

test("test api calls", () => {
     jest.spyOn(helperFunctions , "apiCall1").mockImplementation(jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(123)));

    render(<MyComponent/>)

    /// other testing details .....
}
```

If you want to mock `axios` see Jest's documentation on mocking: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

Here's another stack overflow article that might be helpful: [How to mock API calls made within a React component being tested with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657971/how-to-mock-api-calls-made-within-a-react-component-being-tested-with-jest)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply.  I moved the axios call out to a helper function. I made a single reusable function that takes parameters so it hits the appropriate endpoint and sets the correct state. I also read the article and went through the code there. I added waitFor to my test and I'm still getting the same spinner component being loaded. In the jest.spyOn call, at the end where you pass 123 to Promise.resolve, what value should that be? Mocked data from each of the 3 api endpoints? I appreciate your time, I'm really stuck here.

Comment: that value should be whatever you want to mock. Yes, It represents the value returned from the api endpoint

Comment: Thank you. Should it be updating the state inside my component? For instance in your example should it be setting the state of data1 inside the rendered test component be set to 123?

Comment: Your component will used the mocked value of the apiCall. So whatever you return from the mocked call, will be set in state.  If this answer was helpful, will you mark is as the correct answer?

Comment: Marked. Thank you for your help